# Castle ActiveRecord/NHibernate System.Data.Services dependency and Mono 2.4.2.3

Tags: nhibernate, mono, castle-activerecord

Getting the following compilation error trying to port ASP.Net MVC application using Castle ActiveRecord to a mod_mono server.

Is System.Data.Services not available with mono? If not, do I have to throw out version 2.0 of Castle ActiveRecord framework since it has this dependency, or is there an alternative?

** (/usr/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe:7457): WARNING **: The following assembly referenced from /local/web/mn/bin/NHibernate.Linq.dll could not be loaded:
     Assembly:   System.Data.Services    (assemblyref_index=3)
     Version:    3.5.0.0
     Public Key: b77a5c561934e089
The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly

Comment: http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td25016144%7Ca25016144

Comment: System.Data.Services is not implemented in Mono: http://www.mono-project.com/WCF_Development#System.Data.Services.dll

Comment: This seems to be NHibernate.Linq dependency... I'd try compiling ActiveRecord without LINQ support

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this, and hunting around for ActiveRecord didn't find anything, but searching for NHibernate did - it's a recent change to the NHibernate LINQ implementation that adds this in. You can use ActiveRecord and NHibernate without the LINQ DLLs, or there has been a version of the DLL submitted for inclusion in Mono, which at least gets code compiling, although I haven't yet tested what does and doesn't work in the actual LINQ implementation:
The DLL is linked to from here: http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-devel-list/2009-October/033284.html